# Dplyr select(contains()) with dynamic variable

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a DF, which is updated every quarter with new data, i.e. it gets wider every couple of months. In a next step, I would like to calculate the difference of values between the first and the latest observation. Using  `contains()` I would like to select the first and last observation dynamically, avoiding writing the names of the variables again after every update.

In other cases, I have been using `!!sym()` for  `mutate()` like in the following example, which is working fine:

```
df <- df %>%
  mutate(var1 = ifelse(!!sym(first_year) == 0, 1, 0))
```

But when I try, the following, I get an error (`first_year` equals `2008` in this case):

```
df <- df %>%
  select(contains(!!sym(first_year)))

Error: object '2008' not found
```

Ist there a way to use dynamic variables in `select(contains())` or `select(matches())` - or is this not possible?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation of `?contains` states that the first argument should be a character vector:

> ```
> match      A character vector. If length > 1, the union of the matches is taken.
> ```

Therefore, you don't have to use any tidy evaluation function such as `sym()`:

```r
library(dplyr)
x="Spe"
iris %>% select(contains(x)) %>% head()
#>   Species
#> 1  setosa
#> 2  setosa
#> 3  setosa
#> 4  setosa
#> 5  setosa
#> 6  setosa
```

<sup>Created on 2021-03-15 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

However, we have very little information about what you are working with (what do `first_year` and `df` look like?); this answer might be incorrect because of that.

Comment: Thanks - sometimes the answer seems to be too easy. :) Your suggestion does exactly what I needed.